# Should I trust Chrome's Audits tool?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-inspector, vendor-prefix

Do you know Audits tab from chrome's inspector? I just found out this tab's use and I think it is great but I wonder if the sugestions done there are reliable.

FOr example it says I shouln't use -webkit-border-radius, which seems right as it as a really old rule. Problem is... are this suggestions focused on a general good use of web developing for most common used browsers or are they refering to chrome only and more specifically to the current version of chrome?

Comment: Let's focus on this `-webkit-border-radius`. Why would you use it ? `border-radius` is very old.

Comment: comes from scss snippets, but anyway, the question is the same: are advices very general or very specific (only chrome browser and only current version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're suggesting not too use a vendor specific prefix then that's because that rule has been pretty much accepted by everyone. The Google Chrome team have a lot to do with standards, as does Mozilla, Apple, Microsoft and Opera (along with many others).

A lot of the things are very generic performance guidelines to reduce page load time and you should be fine following them.